# Limit of complex exponential raised to factorial

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

This issue has stumped me;

I'm trying to justify why

if

$$z_0 =\exp(2qi\pi)$$ where $q$ is some rational number, then
$${z_0^n}^!=1$$ for large enough n.

So far I've tried to write $z_0$ in $\cos +i\sin$ form but I end up with;

$${z_0^n}^!=\cos(2qn!\pi)+i\sin(2qn!\pi)$$ and I don't know how this can equal 1 as n increases

I also tried $e^{2qin!\pi} $ but I'm not sure how I can manipulate this given the rules of complex exponents.

A general direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $q$ as $\frac ab$, with $a\in\Bbb Z$, and $b\in\Bbb N$. So, if $n\geqslant b$,$$z_0^{\,n!}=\exp\left(2n!\frac ab\pi i\right)=1,$$since $\frac{n!}b\in\Bbb N$, and therefore $n!\frac ab\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Ahhh that's such a nice simple answer, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.